# Efficiently select subset of rows by rank

Tags: r, data.table, ranking

How do you use `data.table` to select a subset of rows by rank? I have a large data set and I hope to do so efficiently.

```
> dt <- data.table(id=1:200, category=sample(LETTERS, 200, replace=T))
> dt[,count:=length(id), by=category]
> dt
      id category count
  1:   1        O    13
  2:   2        O    13
 ---                   
199: 170        N     3
200: 171        H     3
```

What I want to do is to efficiently change the category to 'OTHER' for any category not in the `k` most common ones. Something along the lines of:

```
dt[rank > 5,category:="OTHER", by=category]
```

I'm new to `data.table` and I'm not quite sure how to get the rank in an efficient way. Here's a way that works, but seems clunky.

```
counts <- unique(dt$count)
decision <- max(counts[rank(-counts)>5])
dt[count<=decision, category:='OTHER']
```

I would appreciate any advice. To be honest, I don't even need to the 'count' column if it's not necessary.

Comment: I think this is a bit tricky as of now. For example, if the `counts` for all `category` gave the same number, then how do you want to compute the `rank`? I mean, how would k-most common ones be chosen in that case? Basically, there'll be some category that'll have identical count. How do you want to resolve the ties there? Which ones are kept and which ones are changed to "Other"?

Comment: Oh and btw: instead of `sample(rep(LETTERS, 1000), 200)` you should do: `sample(LETTERS, 200, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip about replace=T!

Comment: Seems about right, another small comment - use `.N` instead of `length(id)`, but yeah, you'll have to run through the data twice since you can't make the decision about a particular row, without first going through all of the rows (you can probably make the last part a bit more compact but without much/any efficiency impact)

Comment: It seems like `smallcats <- dt[,names(sort(table(category)))[-(1:k)]]` will get you the categories that aren't in the top `k` and then `dt[category %in% smallcats,category:="OTHER"]` can assign. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. The condition you're passing on the last line doesn't look like it would work, since it has a length equal to the number of categories, not the number of rows of `dt`.

Comment: @Frank you're doing smth else; run OP code to compare

Comment: @eddi. Ah, I see. The OP wants to keep categories with the top `k` frequencies, including categories that are tied. This is different from how I interpreted "the `k` most common ones" (which would be exactly `k` categories)... Either choice could lead to some strange behavior, depending on the frequency of ties among the larger categories. Also, my suggestion didn't even do what I wanted it to; I should have used `sort` with `decreasing=TRUE`.